# Webkit source code in AOSP

Tags: android, webkit, android-source

From what I've seen in the posts online, Webkit source code used to be under the folder named "external" of AOSP, however, it's not there anymore in Android 6. Search did not give me any results. Which folder did they move this to?

Thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @odexcide Which folder did they move this in AOSP?

Comment: Webkit is no longer relevant in AOSP because they use a chromium-based WebView now instead of a webkit-based WebView. Thus, it was removed.